# Show that that no $x$ exist that makes the expression independent of other variables.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Assume you have the expression

$$\frac{\beta_2(1-x)-\beta_1-x\beta_0}{\beta_0+\beta_1},$$

if I choose $x=1$ this expression becomes $-1$ and is independent of the $\beta$'s. I have a similar expression

$$\frac{\beta_1-x\beta_0-x\beta_2}{\beta_0+\beta_1}.$$

**I want to show that no matter what $x$ is, this last expression can not be independent of the $\beta$'s. Do you see how to do this?**

If I try with $x=0, x=1$ it is clear that the expression varies with the $\beta$'s. I don't quite see how to show this.

Comment: Your second expression reads $1-\frac{(x+1)\beta_0+x\beta_2}{\beta_0+\beta_1}$ so it is obvious assuming $\beta_2$ and $\beta_1$ are independent. In general, what you're after is that the numerator must be a constant multiple of $\beta_0+\beta_1$ which you can solve by equating coefficients.

Comment: Another way to say it is that you want solve for $x$ such that the partial derivatives with respect to each $\beta_i$ are all zero.

Comment: Your (counter) examples show that your second expression does depend on x. That´s it.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks, if you want you can post it as an answer and I'll accept.